# How to implement an elgg-like persistence of objects into the database in java

Tags: java, elgg

I've been using elgg for a while now. I'm mostly developing in java. I was wondering if there is any engine out there written in java that could help in managing persistence of objects into the database so that all metadata related to all objects get stored in a single table and gets related to the owner object via a GUID reffering to the owner object.

From [elgg](http://learn.elgg.org/en/latest/design/database.html):

> 'In Elgg, everything runs on a unified data model, based on atomic units of data called entities.
>
> Plugins are strongly discouraged from dealing with database issues themselves, which makes for a more stable system that also has visible benefits for the end user. Content created by different plugins can be mixed together in consistent ways, which are programmed using generic principles - in other words, plugins are faster to develop, and are at the same time much more powerful.'

I'm really interested in looking at how I can use a single table, the metastrings table, to store all metadata and annotations relating to the various objects I have in the database.

From [elgg](http://learn.elgg.org/en/latest/design/database.html):

> 'Metastrings contain the actual string of metadata which is linked to by the metadata and annotations tables.
>
> This is to avoid duplicating strings, saving space and making database lookups more efficient.'

I would greatly appreciate links to working projects, or a breakdown of the concepts I'd have to make work with/ follow to achieve this.